# UITableView - multiple sections repeat themselves after scrolling to next page (using Parse)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, parse-platform

I'm using storyboards with a custom `UITableViewCell` displaying four images inside of a `PFQueryTableViewController` (which subclasses `UITableView`).

When the first page loads it displays the first 24 objects properly. When the second page loads it repeats the first 24 objects from the first page and appends the next batch of 24 objects. On the third page, it repeats the first page's 24 objects appended to the second page's 24 objects along with the third page's 24 objects.

I'd appreciate any help with what I need to change in my code to get the correct set of objects to display on the appropriate page when scrolled.

I'm using `Parse` and this subclasses `PFQueryTableViewController`. Since I'm displaying four photos (objects) per row I created an array called `groupedObjectIds` which contains arrays of arrays containing the four objects.

Here's the `.h` file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
@interface TestTableViewController : PFQueryTableViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber *institutionID;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CLLocationManager *locationManager;

- (IBAction)insertCurrentLocation:(id)sender;
@end
```

Here's the `.m` file:

```
#import "TestTableViewController.h"

@interface TestTableViewController ()
@end

@implementation TestTableViewController
NSMutableArray *groupedObjectIds;
@synthesize locationManager = _locationManager;
@synthesize institutionID;

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder    
{        
    self = [super initWithCoder:aCoder];

    if (self)            
    {        
        // Customize the table            
        // The className to query on            
        self.className = @"profilePhoto";

        // The key of the PFObject to display in the label of the default cell style            
        self.textKey = @"text";

        // Whether the built-in pull-to-refresh is enabled            
        self.pullToRefreshEnabled = YES;

        // Whether the built-in pagination is enabled            
        self.paginationEnabled = YES;

        // The number of objects to show per page            
        self.objectsPerPage = 24;

        //self.shouldReloadOnAppear = NO;            
    }        
    return self;        
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

   if (scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.contentOffset.y < (self.view.bounds.size.height)) {
      if (![self isLoading]) {
         NSLog(@"pulling next page");
         //groupedObjectIds = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
         [self loadNextPage];
      }
   }
}

#pragma mark - UIViewController
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
   [super viewDidUnload];
   [self setInstitutionID:nil];

   // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
   // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

#pragma mark - UIViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];

   NSLog(@"entered viewdidload");
   groupedObjectIds = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   if (![CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) {            
   }

   //[[self locationManager] startUpdatingLocation];

   // Listen for annotation updates. Triggers a refresh whenever an annotation is dragged and dropped.
   //[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(loadObjects) name:@"geoPointAnnotiationUpdated" object:nil];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
   [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
   [super viewDidAppear:animated];

   //if (self.shouldReloadOnAppear) {
   //    self.shouldReloadOnAppear = NO;
   //    [self loadObjects];
   //}
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
   [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
   [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {        
   if (indexPath.section == self.objects.count/4) {
      // this behavior is normally handled by PFQueryTableViewController, but we are using sections for each object and we must handle this ourselves
      UITableViewCell *cell = [self tableView:tableView cellForNextPageAtIndexPath:indexPath];
      return cell;
   }
   else{
      //NSLog(@"index path is: %@", indexPath);
      NSLog(@"indexpath.section is: %d", indexPath.section);
      // A date formatter for the creation date.    
      UITableViewCell *cell = (PFTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ImageCell"];

      if (cell == nil) {
          cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier: @"ImageCell"];
          //[cell.photoButton addTarget:self action:@selector(didTapOnPhotoAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
      }
      UIImageView *img1 = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:1000];
      UIImageView *img2 = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:1001];
      UIImageView *img3 = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:1002];
      UIImageView *img4 = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:1003];
      NSLog(@"groupedobjectids in cellforrow count is: %d", groupedObjectIds.count);
      //if([groupedObjectIds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row])
      //if(indexPath.row < groupedObjectIds.count)
      //{
      NSMutableArray *newArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
      [newArray  addObjectsFromArray:[groupedObjectIds objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
      //NSLog(@"newArray count is: %d", newArray.count);
      //NSLog(@"object at index 0 is: %@", [newArray objectAtIndex:0]);
      if([newArray objectAtIndex:0])
      {
         NSString *objectID = [newArray objectAtIndex:0];
         for(PFObject *object in self.objects)
         {
            if([objectID isEqualToString: [object objectId]])
            {
               PFFile *imageFile = [object objectForKey:@"thumbnail"];
               NSData *imageData = [imageFile getData];
               UIImage *selectedPhoto = [UIImage imageWithData: imageData];
               img1.image = selectedPhoto;
            }
         }
      }
      if([newArray objectAtIndex:1])
      {
         NSString *objectID = [newArray objectAtIndex:1];
         for(PFObject *object in self.objects)
         {
            if([objectID isEqualToString: [object objectId]])
            {
               PFFile *imageFile = [object objectForKey:@"thumbnail"];
               NSData *imageData = [imageFile getData];
               UIImage *selectedPhoto = [UIImage imageWithData: imageData];
               img2.image = selectedPhoto;
            }
         }
      }
      if([newArray objectAtIndex:2])
      {
         NSString *objectID = [newArray objectAtIndex:2];
         for(PFObject *object in self.objects)
         {
            if([objectID isEqualToString: [object objectId]])
            {
               PFFile *imageFile = [object objectForKey:@"thumbnail"];
               NSData *imageData = [imageFile getData];
               UIImage *selectedPhoto = [UIImage imageWithData: imageData];
               img3.image = selectedPhoto;
            }
         }
      }
      if([newArray objectAtIndex:3])
      {
         NSString *objectID = [newArray objectAtIndex:3];
         for(PFObject *object in self.objects)
         {
            if([objectID isEqualToString: [object objectId]])
            {
               PFFile *imageFile = [object objectForKey:@"thumbnail"];
               NSData *imageData = [imageFile getData];
               UIImage *selectedPhoto = [UIImage imageWithData: imageData];
               img4.image = selectedPhoto;
            }
         }
      }
      //}        
      return cell;
   }
}

#pragma mark - PFQueryTableViewController

- (void)objectsWillLoad {
   [super objectsWillLoad];

   // This method is called before a PFQuery is fired to get more objects
}    

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
   return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {        
   int j = self.objects.count / 4;
   NSLog(@"number of sections in tableview: %d", j);
   return j;
}

- (void)objectsDidLoad:(NSError *)error {
   [super objectsDidLoad:error];
   //NSLog(@"inside objects did load");
   NSMutableArray *arrayOfFour = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

   int i = 1;
   NSLog(@"self objects count is: %d", self.objects.count);
   for (PFObject *eachObject in self.objects) {            
      NSLog(@"object ID is: %@", [eachObject objectId]);
      [arrayOfFour addObject:[eachObject objectId]];
      if(i%4==0)
      {
         //NSLog(@"mod 4 is 0");
         [groupedObjectIds addObject: arrayOfFour];
         //[arrayOfFour removeAllObjects];
         //arrayOfFour = nil;
         arrayOfFour = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
      }
      //NSLog(@"i is: %d", i);
      i++;
   }
   NSMutableArray *newArrayOfFour = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   //[newArrayOfFour addObjectsFromArray:[groupedObjectIds objectAtIndex:0]];
   newArrayOfFour = [groupedObjectIds objectAtIndex:0];
   //NSLog(@"newarrayoffour count is: %d", newArrayOfFour.count);
   for(int i = 0; i<newArrayOfFour.count; i++)
   {
      //NSLog(@"object id here is: %@", [newArrayOfFour objectAtIndex:i]);
   }
   //NSLog(@"groupedObjectIds count in objectsdidload is: %d", groupedObjectIds.count);
   // This method is called every time objects are loaded from Parse via the PFQuery
}

- (PFQuery *)queryForTable {
   /*if (![PFUser currentUser]) {
      PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.className];
      [query setLimit:0];
      return query;
   }*/
   PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"profilePhoto"];        
   [query orderByAscending:@"createdAt"];        
   return query;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have a reusable cell identifier Problem, try to set that in the tableviewcontroller method `cellForRowAtIndexpath:(NSIndexpath*)indexPath` for a allocated custom cell you have created with storyboards, so that the controller does not have to allocate a cell for each object in your list!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. It turned out that when specifying query for table I used:

```
query.cachePolicy = PFCachePolicy.CacheThanNetwork
```

instead use:

```
query.cachePolicy = PFCachePolicy.CacheElseNetwork
```

And it was first loading objects from cache. I have run the code on one and the same device several times, so the objects were found and appended. After, the query requested new objects from Network and they were completely the same, and these objects were as well appended to the tableView. Maybe you are heaving the same problem.